# Julia Variance Q

Tags: julia

Ok have been wresting with this for a little while now.

I am calculating a rolling variance. I am using a manual variance calculation and then cross checking with the `var()`

To follow along will use my variance calculation adjusting for n-1

Calculate the mean of the sample. ...
Subtract the mean from each data point. ...
Square each result. ...
Find the sum of the squared values. ...
Divide by n - 1, where n is the number of data points.

```
    xi = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]
    # initalize arrays
    xi_sum = zeros(xi)
    xi_mean = zeros(xi)
    xi_mean_dev = zeros(xi)
    xi_mean_dev_sq = zeros(xi)
    xi_sum_mean_dev_sq = zeros(xi)
    xi_var_corrected = zeros(xi)
    # loop
    i=1
    for i = 1:size(xi,1)
    xi_sum[i] = sum(xi[1:i])
    xi_mean[i] = xi_sum[i] / i
    xi_mean_dev[i] = xi[i] - xi_mean[i]
    xi_mean_dev_sq[i] = xi_mean_dev[i]^2
    xi_sum_mean_dev_sq[i] = sum(xi_mean_dev_sq[1:i])
    xi_var_corrected[i] = xi_sum_mean_dev_sq[i] / (i-1) # n-1
end
```

With output:

```
julia> xi_var_corrected
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 NaN
   0.25
   0.625
   1.16667
   1.875
   2.75
```

If verify with var()

```
var_verify = zeros(xi)
    for i = 1:size(xi,1)
        var_verify[i] = var(xi[1:i],corrected=true)
    end

julia> var_verify
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 NaN
   0.5
   1.0
   1.66667
   2.5
   3.5
```

Also with:

```
julia> var(xi)
3.5
```

If I validate in R:

```
> test = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
> var(test)
[1] 3.5
```

Final is 3.5 vs my 2.75.

My question is - im at a loss as to why my manual variance calculation is not providing the same answer as var(), R var().

Reason i'm breaking down variance is that in calculating the regression slope, there is a lot of cross over calculations in the stdev, correlation - so if i can break it down, i can cut down processing time + if i calculate on every [i] instead over the ranges as above. I can make it faster. Anyway anyone see where im going wrong with my variance calculation?

Thanks

## Edit

I see it now - for each 1:i

I need the final mean at each i, then subtract that from the previous values to center it correctly.

Comment: `xi_mean[i]` that's not actually the mean until the end, so you're not centering it by the correct value. If you want to do it like this then you need to build an online version.

Comment: online version?

Comment: I'm thinking about to how to code this now after realizing its the sample mean that is needed. Trying to build it with speed in mind.

Comment: Chris - Onlinestats.jl?

Comment: You have to be careful and scale by the full sums in the end. For an example, see the Welford algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm . I am not sure how to do this with correlations but you'd need to either find or develop similar tricks. This is more of a math problem than a programming issue. If you want to discuss more, I suggest joining the Julia Slack and discussing in #statistics : https://slackinvite.julialang.org/